# 404 When Not Using Incognito

Tags: http-status-code-404

A very strange thing is happening on my site. When I go to a certain page I get a 404 error, but the file is definitely there. In fact when I open up the same page in incognito, the page loads without issue. What could be causing this?

This is an ASP.NET application on a Windows Server 2012, with IIS 8.5.

I checked the log files, and I'm not seeing any references to that request with the 404. I see a few that returned 200's, but nothing with a 404.

Comment: Tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yep, I tried that, it worked, but when I closed the browser and opened it again I got the 404. Multiple people are having the same problem too.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. There was a missing binding in IIS.